# android emulator has no skin

Tags: android

I'm using ubuntu, and trying to use command line to build the android source code.

After I built android source code, I typed `emulator` command to run Android emulator, then I got a no-skin emulator.

Could anyone tell me how to change it to full-skin mode?

Comment: I've got the same problem, from one start to the other the skin suddenly disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try using emulator's `-skin` and -`skindir` command line parameters.